# Modificar TAG que não possui tal class

Tags: html, css

Quando queremos modificar uma div, e ela tem uma class tal, é fácil.

```
.umaclass{
   /*Formatação*/
}
```

Mas vamos supor que eu queira pegar uma div que não possui tal class, sem modificar as que tem a class... Como faço?

Por exemplo:

---

Tenho várias divs com a mesma class, teste e testando
:

```
<div class="teste testando"></div>
<div class="teste testando"></div>
<div class="teste testando"></div>

<div class="teste"></div> //SOMENTE ESSA SER MODIFICADA, SEM MODIFICAR AS OUTRAS
```

Mas quero modificar somente a class teste mas sem modificar os que tem a class testando como faço isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A resposta do Anderson Carlos Woss provavelmente atenderá suas necessidades, mas caso queira saber, também existe o `:not` no css, olha:

```css
.teste:not(.testando){
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="teste testando"></div>
<div class="teste testando"></div>
<div class="teste testando"></div>

<div class="teste"></div>
```

Ele aceita um seletor simples como argumento, e selecionará todos os elementos que não se encaixam naquele seletor

Comment: Obrigado, Artur, o que eu queria fazer, com o not deu certo!

Comment: @LucasCarvalho Disponha :)

Answer (score 2):

CSS funciona do mais genérico para o mais específico. Ou seja, você pode estilizar todas as `div` com apenas `div { ... }` e depois estilizar `.umaclass` sobrescrevendo as propriedades desejadas.

Veja um exemplo:

```css
.teste {
  display: none;
}

.testando {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="teste testando">1</div>
<div class="teste testando">2</div>
<div class="teste testando">3</div>

<div class="teste">4</div
```

Perceba que a última `div` mantém a estilização padrão, definida em `.teste`, enquanto as outras foram estilizadas conforme `.testando`.

Comment: Mas por exemplo. Quero por um display none na class teste mas que as outras, que possuem a class testando, continuem aparecendo.

Comment: Consegui com o not: do Artur :)

Comment: @LucasCarvalho o Not é a melhor forma de fazer isso, mas o que ele quis dizer que você pode botar a class do display none somente no objeto que você não quer que apareça que ele vai sobrescrever o display para você.

Comment: @LucasCarvalho o funcionamento é o mesmo. Você define o comportamento de `.teste` como `display: none` e depois *especializa* o estilo de `.testando` com `display: block`, para que tais elementos continuem aparecendo. O termo *especializa* é porque uma vez que os elementos `.testando` também possuem a classe `.teste`, eles devem possuir seu estilo. Ou seja, parte de um estilo genérico, `.teste`, para um mais específico, `.testando`. Alterei a resposta para esse exemplo.

Comment: Entendi, vendo aqui, consigo fazer com os 2 mesmo.